# How to extract specific data with headers included

Tags: c#, timestamp

I have data in the following form and I want to extract specific information from it:

```
    f
    hj
13:45
    A
    Cd
    F
    RT
14:10
    df
    gj
    G
.. goes on
```

Let's say, I want everything between `F` and `gj`.. with the timestamps included, how would I go about doing that. I know how to get the lines from F to gj but I dont know how to include the timestamp also, I'm very new to c#. Any help will be appreciated.

Output should look something like

```
13:45
    F
    RT
14:10
    df
    gj
```

**EDIT :::**

```
public static void search_HstrLog()
        {
            int counter = 0;

            string[] hist_Logs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\logs");

            string line;

            for (int i = 0; i < hist_Logs.Count(); i++)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(hist_Logs[i]);

                bool betweenStartAndEnd = false;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    {
                        {

                        string start = "RUN";
                        string end = "STOP";


                            if(line.Contains(start))
                                betweenStartAndEnd = true;

                            if (betweenStartAndEnd || isTimeStamp(line))
                                Console.WriteLine(line);

                            if(line.Contains(end))
                                betweenStartAndEnd = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }

    public static bool isTimeStamp(string line)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d{2}:\d{2} ?[a-z]*$");
    }
```

This is what I have right now, the regex has been updated lightly because a timestamp line can also include text along with it, including the start and end term, for example, `14:22 RUN`.

Also, this is a more specific accurate version of what the data looks like

```
14:22 RUN
     - abc
     - bfg
         dmf
            -rkc
15:33 
     dbv
        -fjh
        -fjs
```

So in the case above, if start was `RUN` and end was `fjh`, then the result would be ...

```
 14:22 RUN
         - abc
         - bfg
             dmf
                -rkc
 15:33 
      dbv
         -fjh
```

If start was `bfg` and end was `dbv`, output would be -

```
14:22 
    - bfg
         dmf
            -rkc
15:33 
     dbv
```

Comment: This is not clear.  If you know hot to get the lines then why would that not include the time stamps?  Are you asking how to parse the values to `DateTime`?  Can you show any attempts you've made so far and tell us specifically why it didn't work?

Comment: I actually search for F and once that is found, write every line after until I find gj, However I'm not sure how to get the first time stamp that I missed. How do I go back and retreive it?

Comment: Parsing text (files) is always a bit more tedious as one would hope for. Usually it requires a more or less primitive parser implementation.

Comment: The grammar you might need can look like this: ``DataBlock ::= <Time> | <Time><TextBlock>. TextBlock ::= <Text> | <Text><TextBlock>.`` If you parse this way, you always have the time as part of the DataBlock and after completely parsing a DataBlock, you look for your Text "F" in it, then change state and parse on until you find a DataBlock with a Text "gj" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to keep track if you are between the start and end values and then you need a way to identify a time stamp.  Here I use a regular expression, but you can change that to anything else including using `DateTime.ParseExact`.  You may also need to use `string.Trim` if you need to remove leading and trailing white space before comparing.

```
string start = "F";
string end = "gj";
bool betweenStartAndEnd = false;
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    if(line == start)
        betweenStartAndEnd = true;

    if(betweenStartAndEnd || isTimeStamp(line))
        Console.WriteLine(line);

    if(line == end)
        betweenStartAndEnd = false;
}

public static bool isTimeStamp(string line)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d{2}:\d{2}$");
}
```

Comment: This is producing output but I don't see the first timestamp before F. That timestamp is still missing

Comment: @sparta93 Try `isTimeStamp(line.Trim())` to make sure all leading and trailing white space is removed.

Comment: This works for me for an input like `var lines = new List<string> { "f", "hj", "13:45", "A", "Cd", "F", "RT", "14:10", "df", "gj", "G" };`.  Try debugging to see exactly what the value of the "line" is for the first time stamp.

Comment: Hey, please check my edit. I've tried a bunch of things but I'm still not getting the first timestamp. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `^\d{2}:\d{2}` for the regular expression.  Basically just check if the line begins with a time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a state machine like the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            FIND_START,
            COLLECT_DATA,
            STOP_COLLECTING
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                    "14:22 RUN\n" +
                         "- abc\n" +
                         "- bfg\n" +
                             "dmf\n" +
                                "-rkc\n" +
                    "15:33\n" +
                         "dbv\n" +
                            "-fjh\n" +
                            "-fjs\n";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

            string inputLine = "";
            string output = "";
            State state = State.FIND_START;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case State.FIND_START:
                        if (inputLine.Contains("RUN"))
                        {
                            output += inputLine + "\n";
                            state = State.COLLECT_DATA;
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.COLLECT_DATA:
                        output += inputLine + "\n";
                        if (inputLine == "dbv") state = State.STOP_COLLECTING;
                        break;
                    case State.STOP_COLLECTING:
                        break;

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just changing the start from "F" to "hj".  It would still not include the first time stamp if you change the start to "F".

Comment: The first time stamp is 13:45 which will be included.  The code is an example of how to collect a portion of a text string and can be modified as required.

Comment: The question was how to include all time stamps regardless of the start and end.  Your code does not do that.  All you did was change the start so it was before the first time stamp.

Comment: When parsing text, you can't just look for specific data without knowing the precise sequence of data prior to the data.  The time is meaningless without associating it with other headers.  Text parsing isn't simple.  I've been doing it for 40 years and understand how to properly associate the data correctly.

Comment: @jdweng Hey, I tried your solution but it did not work, check my edit above for more specific description. Sorry if problem was vague. Thanks!

Comment: @jdweng Please check last example in my edit.. Your code is not grabbing the first timestamp if first search term is not along with it. I need the first timestamp under which `RUN` or any other first search term shows up and second timestamp under which `dbv` shows up.

Comment: This is typical type problems with text parsing.  Is there something else in the file that will indicate the timestamp?  The only other solution would be to use Regex to locate a string with a time format XX:XX